# Multipoint Geometry Query for ArcGIS Rest API returning only a single result

Tags: python, api, rest, geometry, arcgis

I've seen this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60231193/how-to-optimize-api-calls-for-a-large-dataset-using-python) and also followed the same syntax specified [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/common-data-types/geometry-objects.htm) and when querying the NFHL [api](https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer/28/query) - with this [query](https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer/28/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=%7B%0D%0A++%22points%22+%3A+%5B%5B-97.06138%2C32.837%5D%2C%5B-97.06133%2C32.836%5D%2C%5B-97.06124%2C32.834%5D%2C%5B-97.06127%2C32.832%5D%5D%2C%0D%0A++%22spatialReference%22+%3A+%7B%22wkid%22+%3A+4326%7D%0D%0A%7D&geometryType=esriGeometryMultipoint&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&distance=&units=esriSRUnit_Foot&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=false&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&havingClause=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnExtentOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&quantizationParameters=&featureEncoding=esriDefault&f=pjson) using the same lat/longs specified and the syntax of the multipoint:

{
"points" : [[-97.06138,32.837],[-97.06133,32.836],[-97.06124,32.834],[-97.06127,32.832]],
"spatialReference" : {"wkid" : 4326}
}

I only get a single result. Is this perhaps a limit on the API for multipoint or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem, I have the same question.